# Why is my kitchen faucet dripping even after water is shut-off?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet

Kitchen faucet (two separate handles, pull-out hose, Price-Pfister Catalina model) is dripping from the faucet itself. I shut the water from below the sink, determined it's a cold water, unscrewed the handle, removed and replaced the cartridge. **However**. As soon as I screw the cartridge in place, water starts dripping (both cold and hot water is shut off). If I unscrew the cartridge, water stops dripping (and nothing comes out of cartridge hole, so I suppose under-sink shut-off is ok). I tried unscrewing the hot water handle, same behavior exactly.

**Question:** Why the water is dripping and how do I troubleshoot/fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

both or one of your shut off valves is not shutting off completely and has a small drip which builds up in the cartridge housing. the new cartridge fills that void up causing it to leak again.

This is the only logical explanation i can think of.

You didnt say if you replaced the cartridge with a new or seals.  So if not the do so and it should stop leaking if you do it right.

Comment: It was indeed not 100% complete shut off, my replacement cartridge was also leaking, apparently. Getting a second cartridge solved the leaking problem. Thanks.